# Docker Compose raise an AccessDeniedExpcetion

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to compose the ELK architecture by using docker compose. The following is the compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch_assets:
    image: elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    command: /bin/true

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    volumes_from:
      - elasticsearch_assets:rw
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch_assets
```

And here folliwing a screenshot of the project structure:

[image]

When I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
Starting elkdocker_elasticsearch_assets_1
Starting elkdocker_elasticsearch_1
Attaching to elkdocker_elasticsearch_assets_1, elkdocker_elasticsearch_1
elkdocker_elasticsearch_assets_1 exited with code 0
elasticsearch_1        | [2016-03-22 01:28:59,939][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: your kernel is buggy and you should upgrade
elasticsearch_1        | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.scripts' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts)
elasticsearch_1        | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts
elasticsearch_1        |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
elasticsearch_1        |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
elasticsearch_1        |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
elasticsearch_1        |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
elasticsearch_1        |    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
elasticsearch_1        |    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
elasticsearch_1        |    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:337)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:248)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:196)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
elasticsearch_1        |    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
elasticsearch_1        | Refer to the log for complete error details.
elkdocker_elasticsearch_1 exited with code 1
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Main issue is `Unable to access 'path.scripts' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts)`. Looks like a permission issue.

Comment: @warmoverflow I already know that but why a permission issue?

Comment: Is your project folder under `Users`?

Comment: yes under `/Users/<myname>/<foldername>/<projectfolder>`

Comment: Since your `yml` file is at the same level as the `config` folder, I wonder if the path should be set as `./config:container_path`, or try absolute path.

Comment: no it doesn't work. it is a permission issue not a path issue

Comment: See this issue here https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/27. The image runs with an `elasticsearch` user which is unable to access a host folder. Need to change the user id in the container as directed in the link. See the last two posts.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this error 
**Unable to access 'path.scripts' error**
just create a sub folder called scripts under the config folder
it will  fix the error

./elasticsearch/config ==> mkdir ./elasticsearch/config/scripts

Answer (score 0):

Change the docker compose to something like this

-v /elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

instead of pointing to empty directory